# Computing the Jacobian for change of variables, differentiate w.r.t. to new or old variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If I go from $x,y$ variables to new $u,v$ variables in integration, is the Jacobian then the determinant of the matrix of partials $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ or $x_u, x_v$ and $y_u, y_v$?

I think it is the determinant of $x_u, x_v$ and  $y_u, y_v$, but this seems to be in reverse of what we do in single-variable calculus, where, say, we let $u = x^2$, $u$ being the new variable of integration, then we differentiate with respect to the *old* variable to get $2xdx = du$ and hence $du/2x = dx$, and our "Jacobian" is $1/2x$.

What is wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: What you really do in 1-variable is $x=\sqrt u$, $dx=(1/2)u^{-1/2}\,du$.

Comment: ah, ok, got it.  Thanks so much, @GerryMyerson.

Answer (score 1):

Think that $${\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\color{green}{\partial(u,v)}}\right|\,\color{green}{{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v},$$ like a fraction. In the same fashion: $${\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v = \left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\color{blue}{\partial(x,y)}}\right|\,\color{blue}{{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y}.$$ In the single variable case:  $${\rm d}x = \frac{{\rm d}x}{\color{green}{{\rm d}u}}\,\color{green}{{\rm d}u}, \quad {\rm d}u = \frac{{\rm d}u}{\color{blue}{{\rm d}x}}\,\color{blue}{{\rm d}x}. $$ These objects are not fractions but there's no harm in thinking of them as such, just to get calculations right.